# Rails Capistrano - Whenever Cron appends cron jobs for every Deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, capistrano, whenever, whenever-capistrano

I am using:

```
Ruby     1.9.3
whenever 0.9.4
Rails    3.2
and capistrano/whenever extension.
```

Whenever the deployment happens, it adds entries to the crontab file after each deployment.  Since 5 deployments, there are 40 entries in `crontab -l`, as schedule.rb has 8 cron entries.  For each release there are different entries.  Should it not overwrite the entries by default?

It recreates entries everytime mentioned in `schedule.rb` file.

Comment: Yes, it should be overwriting them. Could you please include some more information which may help us diagnose your problem? What is in your `schedule.rb`? What is in the `crontab`? Do you have any unusual deployment code? What happens if you empty the `crontab` and re-deploy on the clean system? .......

Comment: The schdule.rb defines 8 simple entries to run a command once a day.  e.g. `every 1.day do <some ruby command> end`

I cleared the crontab and triggered deployment twice.  It added the cron entries two times.

Comment: Please edit the original post, with the actual code. (If it contains sensitive information, you can edit it with dummy data so long as the meaning is not lost.)

Comment: Did you ever figure out this issue?

Comment: Actually yes. I will post an answer.

Comment: would love to see your solution, Sid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that whenever was adding a cron job to the crontab file, with each cron job delimited by a comment line that includes the path to the capistrano releases directory... something like this:

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /home/path/www/to/releases/2070527160502/config/schedule.rb
```

(You can look at the raw crontab file with crontab -e to see what whenever has put in there)

When the next deploy occurs, whenever looks to see if there are comment-delimited cron jobs, but using the *new* release number. It doesn't find that, so it appends new jobs to the crontab file.

My workaround for this problem is to specify the update_crontab task in deploy.rb with the explicit path to schedule.rb like this:

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :update_crontab do
    on roles(:all) do
      within current_path do
        execute :bundle, :exec, :whenever, "--update-crontab", "~/path/to/current/config/schedule.rb"
      end
    end
  end
end
after 'deploy:symlink:release', 'deploy:update_crontab'
```

So the comment delimiters in the crontab file contain the 'current' path and not the 'releases/nnnnnnnnnnn' path.

I suspect that this should not be necessary, but after trying to solve the problem for some time, this what what I ended up with.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are setting

```
set :whenever_identifier, ->{ "#{fetch(:application)}_#{fetch(:stage)}" }
```

If you do not it will pick the default identifier, which is the expanded path of your config/schedule.rb file.

https://github.com/javan/whenever/blob/6e69dd8a6b3e2a8f4b2911b4efa5aab65cdc9dcb/lib/whenever/command_line.rb#L51

```
File.expand_path(@options[:file])
```